# Create Outlook Skype meetings from Excel list of data

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a code for creating Skype meeting in Outlook from Excel data table. The problem with current solution is that if I have for example 2 appointments that need to be send to Outlook calendar the code creates first one as a normal appointment and not a Skype meeting. Then the second one is perfectly fine. Also for some reason it is not able to "Save and Close" appointment although I have `.save` and `.send`. So it is creating first appointment and before changing it to Skype meeting it opens the second one and firstly creating appointment and after that changing it to Skype meeting without "Saving and Closing" both.

As the result I have one standard appointment and the second one is Skype meeting. Both are opened in Outlook and not sent. What can be the possible problem?

```
Sub CreateOutlookAppointments()

' This is a little sloppy. This selects the worksheet named Sheet1. It should be assigned to a variable instead
' It also assumes without providing instruction that your appointments are all on Sheet1
Sheets("Schedule").Select

' Error handling - when an error occurs it will jump to Err_Execute. However in this code, this Error Handler will never
' be used because it is replaced immediately after initial declaration.
On Error GoTo Err_Execute

' Declare the variables that will be used in this code
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application            ' Object to refer to a specific instance of the Outlook Application
Dim olAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem   ' Object to refer to the new appointment
Dim blnCreated As Boolean                    ' Boolean is TRUE/FALSE. Typically used in tests, but is not used for anything in this code
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace             ' Required in order to navigation the folders of the Outlook application
Dim CalFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder       ' Object to refer to the Calendar folder

'***************************************************************
' Added new object to interact with Appointment window
Dim insp As Inspector
'***************************************************************

' i is a standard variable name for a counter/index variable
Dim i As Long

' This forces the code to skip to the next line of code if an error occurs
On Error Resume Next

' Assign the Outlook Application to the object
Set olApp = Outlook.Application

' If the Set fails, try again
If olApp Is Nothing Then
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application

     ' This is where the Boolean is assigned a value. It is pointless because there is no test of the variable anywhere
     blnCreated = True

    ' Clear all error codes that may have been created when the olApp assignment failed initially
    Err.Clear
Else

    ' A pointless boolean assignment. I guess they had intended for there to be a test of it later. Never happens
    blnCreated = False
End If

' This clears all error handlers and means the default Excel error handling applies
On Error GoTo 0

' Assign the NameSpace to navigate the Outlook folder tree
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

' Find the Calendar folder in the namespace
Set CalFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

' Assign the counter, in this case i refers to the ROW so it starts at row 2 in your worksheet
i = 2

' DO everything between this line and LOOP until it finds a cell in column A that is empty. TRIM removes leading/trailing spaces so this treats any cell containing
' only spaces as blank
Do Until Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value) = ""

    ' Create a new appointment and assign it to the olAppt object
    Set olAppt = CalFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

    ' With is a shorthand so you don't need to type it to set values on every property of the object
    With olAppt

        'Define calendar item properties
        ' Column E value + Column F value
        .Start = DateValue(Cells(i, 3).Value) + Cells(i, 4).Value     '+ TimeValue("9:00:00")

        ' Column G value + Column H value
        .Duration = Cells(i, 5).Value       '+TimeValue("10:00:00")

        ' Subject is column A
        .Subject = Cells(i, 1)

        ' Location is column B
        .Location = Cells(i, 2)

        ' Body is column C
        .Body = Cells(i, 7)

        ' BusyStatus will default to Busy
        .BusyStatus = olBusy

        ' How many minutes before event starts should you be reminded is column I
        .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = Cells(i, 6)

        ' Reminders are on by default
        .ReminderSet = True

        ' Required Attendees are on by default
        .RequiredAttendees = "mail@mail.com"

        ' Category is column D
        .Categories = Cells(i, 8)

       '**********************************************************
       ' My inserted code goes here

        ' Assign the new appointment to an Inspector object
        Set insp = .GetInspector

        'Activate the appointment window
        insp.Activate

        ' ALT+HOM to activate the HOME tab and select SFB button OM
        Application.SendKeys ("%HOM")

        ' Body is column C. If you are using conferencing call codes, this should add your BODY text from Excel before the conferencing details
        .Body = .Body & Chr(13) & Cells(i, 3)

       '**********************************************************

        Set insp = Nothing

        ' Save the appointment to the calendar
        .Save

        ' For meetings, uncomment the following line to SEND the invitation
        .Send
    End With

    ' Move to the next row
    i = i + 1
Loop

' Clean up, set objects to NOTHING to clear memory.
Set olAppt = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

' Missing cleanup follows
Set olNs = Nothing
Set CalFolder = Nothing

Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
MsgBox "An error occurred - Exporting items to Calendar."

End Sub
```

Comment: add `DoEvents` or `Application.Wait` to allow outside processing to finish before continuing VBA code execution.